# array of struct won't change

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have a struct array in one of my classes, which itself has an setup method.

```
struct key
{
     int x;
     int y;
};

class myClass
{
    key theKeys[9];
    void setup();
};
```

in the setup method I go through them but they stay the same

```
void myClass::setup()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        theKeys[i].x = i;
        theKeys[i].y = i - 1;
        cout << theKeys[i].x << " " << theKeys[i].y << endl;
    }
}
```

Will return

```
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

What am I doing wrong?
Bear in mind this isn't the actual code from my project, but its pretty much the same.

---

Solved: WOOPS, I fixed it. I wan't go into detail but it actually was working but cout wasn't set up properly so it print the wrong struck that hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Post a minimalisticcode sample demonstrating the problem.

Comment: well, your code is working fine!!!
Check it <a href="http://codepad.org/FQ0dNNrG">here</A>

Comment: How do you create the key structs, with the `new` operator?

Comment: The OP is creating them with `key theKeys[9]`

Comment: thats the thing, The values wont change for some reason, however I've updated since you posted, so their is a bit more context I left out

Comment: *this isn't the actual code from my project, but its pretty much the same* -- please post the actual code.

Comment: The code you've posted [works as expected](http://ideone.com/U555B) (with minimal changes to allow `setup` to be called). Please post some code that demonstrates teh problem.

Comment: I have the same problem.  please post the solution!

Comment: @user396483 In my case, I was printing the struct before I printed it, which made me panic and post here prematurely, hence [Solved, embarrassingly]

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

Create an instance of myClass in the main: `myClass mc;` .  Make a function/methode call to setup: `mc.setup();`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;


struct key
{
     int x;
     int y;
};

class myClass
{
    public:
        key theKeys[9];
        void setup();
};    

void myClass::setup()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        theKeys[i].x = i;
        theKeys[i].y = i - 1;
        cout << theKeys[i].x << " " << theKeys[i].y << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    myClass mc;
    mc.setup();


return 0;
}
```